# with VIM, the quotation parts are colored wrong

Tags: vim, colors, sh

Here is a simple code in bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
str='{}\pear\pinapple{look at this}{look at that}\apple'
str=${str%'{look at this}'*}
echo $str
#######################'
#'

str=${str%{look at this*}
echo $str
#######################
#

str=${str#*{}
echo $str
###########################}
#

str='\'
echo $str
############################'
#
```

It can be run normally in my computer, and the result is as expected:

```
{}\pear\pinapple{look at this}
{}\pear\pinapple
}\pear\pinapple
\
```

However, the color of the codes shown in Vi is weird. As suggested by FDinoff, I use the the command

```
:let g:is_bash = 1 | set ft=sh
```

The color of some codes becomes normal while that of some becomes bad.

The real reason is that the Vi cannot distinguish the real ' { } \' etc.

To illustrative the problem clearly, I list in the figure:

```
1. what Vi shows without :let g:is_bash = 1 | set ft=sh;
    (lines 4 and 19 weird)
2. what Vi shows with :let g:is_bash = 1 | set ft=sh;
    (lines 9, 14 and 19 weird)
3. what Emacs shows.
    (normal)
```

The figure can be find in the following link:

https://plus.google.com/107969501608510514420/posts/YUWKXQcbmZK?pid=6052520323379457698&oid=107969501608510514420

Answer (score 0):

Read `:help sh.vim`. Most likely the problem is that you aren't using syntax highlighting for the right shell. For instance if you run `:let g:is_bash = 1 | set ft=sh` then it would look better. Vim should automatically detect this if you add a proper shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`).

To automatically force bash syntax line add

```
let g:is_bash = 1
```

to your vimrc.

(However I don't know if you want bash syntax highlighting or some other shell type)

Comment: Thanks! For that simple example your suggestion works! But for the real file, there still some problems with Vi, and again it can be shown normally by Emacs! Yes, I want the bash syntax! Would you please see the problem picture in the following link(In the left pic, I didn't use :let g:is_bash = 1 | set ft=sh; while int the right one I use it)?     https://plus.google.com/u/0/107969501608510514420/posts/ZgSrFfyXnDt?pid=6052140701218258098&oid=107969501608510514420

Comment: Obviously now the vim wrongly recognize the pare of {}! The { in Line 5 is an ordinary character: strSource=${strSource#*{} is really equivalent to strSource=${strSource#*"{"}

Comment: Vi cannot deal with the character a='\' with correct color in my computer. The Vi thinks \' is printed ', so \' and the sentences after it are treated quoted staffs...